# undefined method 'validate' for AdServeModel < Couchbase::Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchbase

I got an application that depends on `Couchbase::Model`. I created a class to encapsulate all the nasty database hackage and I need to validate certain attributes in a custom way. So I wrote a custom validation method:

```
class AdServeModel < Couchbase::Model

validate :validate_attributes

[...] (some other stuff happens here)

def validate_attributes
  #First we validate the objects we belong_to
  unless belongsToModels.nil?
    belongsToModels.each do |attribute|
      retrievedClass = attribute.to_s.camelize.constantize.find(
                       send("#{belongsToAttributeName(attrName)}"))
      errors.add(attribute.to_sym, "#{attribute} is invalid") unless !retrievedClass.nil? and retrievedClass.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

But when I try to run this, I get:
`undefined method 'validate' for AdServeModel(id):Class (NoMethodError)`. 
I'm quite stumped. Any pointers as to why this might happen are appreciated. If you need more code please say so in the comments.

Comment: It might be because your class is extending Couchbase::Model  where validate method isn't defined.BTW which version of rails you are using?

Comment: Yeah I can't find the validate method in the Couchbase::Model class. The thing is the code used to work about two weeks ago when I got distracted by other stuff. When I came back and run an `bundle update` it stopped working. I'm on Rails version 3.2.14 btw.

Comment: Well I double checked now and they do `include ActiveModel::Validations` in [active_model](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-model/blob/master/lib/couchbase/active_model.rb). This should incorporate the possibility to us `validate`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine. There are two different methods named `validate` that I know from Rails, one is for [validating records](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html#method-i-validate) (instance method) and [another one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate) (class method) is used for the more general case as it does apply in your scenario.

> > Adds a validation method or block to the class. This is useful when overriding the validate instance method becomes too unwieldy and you’re looking for more descriptive declaration of your validations.

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate) shows that you need to include the `ActiveModel::Validations` module. Yes, Couchbase does include that already in its own `ActiveModel` module, but only if it is available. My guess is that the problem originates from [this line](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-model/blob/596ed2b2c7a70a5f809f77d040c7f383a6c59d71/lib/couchbase/active_model.rb#L5) of the Couchbase source code.

```
return unless defined?(::ActiveModel)
```

With the `::` it accesses the outer module name scope to get the Rails modules. If this module is available, it would continue and include further Rails Active Model modules.

```
base.class_eval do
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
```

Probably, Couchbase it not able to access the Rails module. The best would to check if Couchbase really includes the modules, respectively to get Couchbase find the Rails modules. An alternative/workaround might be to simply include the module yourself.

```
class AdServeModel < Couchbase::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  # ...
end
```

Comment: That actually was the problem! The thing was that Rails got some hiccups because I added the gem in two different ways. First I added it to my Gemfile and just called `bundle install`. Later I thought that I always want to stay up to date and added a git segment to that part. Now I had the gem installed in two different locations. I cleaned all my gems, removed the git annotation and now it works just fine.